# авторизация на сайте cUrl

Tags: php, curl

есть корпоративный сервис, хочу к нему подцепиться для дальнейшего парсинга с помощью cUrl. в Form Data отправляются следующие значения:

[image: Form Data]

```
public function downloadWifi(){

            $url = "https://10.80.1.246/webacs/loginAction....";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); // сохранять куки в файл
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // использовать данные в post
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
              'j_username'=> 'user001',
                    'j_password'=> 'pass001,
                    'spring-security-redirect' => '/pages/common/index.jsp?&selectedCategory=en',
                    'action'=> 'login',

            ));
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            print_r($data);
}
```

в $data получаю ту же самую страницу с вводом логина и пароля. Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка зарылась?

Comment: [curl-getinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php) что говорит? Ну и если проект не маленький, то советую перейти на **guzzle**

Comment: [url] => https://10.80.1.246/webacs/pages/comtQn/login.jsp
[content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 378
[request_size] => 409
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 18
[redirect_count] => 1
[total_time] => 0.593
[namelookup_time] => 2.0E-6
[connect_time] => 0.187
[pretransfer_time] => 0.437
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 10702
[speed_download] => 10702
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0.515
[redi rect_time] => 0.344
[redi rect_url] =>

Comment: [primary_ip] => 10.80.1.246 [certinfo] => Array()
[primary_port] => 443
[local _ip] => 10.84.73.70
[local_port] => 59437

Comment: Посмотрите кукисы и заголовки, которые пришли в ответе. Возможно с их использованием можно будет обращаться к другим страницам